# When display PPT slides on WebBrowser controls in .NET framework, how do I disable all user interaction via mouse / keyboard?

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

When display PPT slides on WebBrowser controls in .NET framework, how do I disable all user interaction via mouse / keyboard?

I've tried to intercept mouse inputs to the WebBrowser by placing it in a usercontrol but got no luck.

Answer (score 1):

As i know - Webbrowser component don't provide some features to control mouse or keyboard inputs, instead of that, it's provide a reach features on controlling links-mouse clicks and other events to DOM document model. So the only way to achieve this as i see - it's a set global hooks on your application. Global hooks is not simple thing, but there is many info's about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any user interaction, why not convert the PowerPoint to a video?
It can be done programmatically. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg985312%28v=office.14%29.aspx).